# Can't add an item to arrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I am currently having an issue where I have outlined the parameters of my constructor and what I want it to take in. However trying to add elements via an ArrayList, I keep getting an error message saying `"identifier expected"`. Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Employer.java:

```
public class Employer {

    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private Employees employees;
    private STP stp;


     Employer(String name, String email, String password){
         this.name = name;
         this.email = email;
         this.password = password;
     }           
}
```

Employers.java:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Employers {

    private ArrayList<Employer> employers = new ArrayList<Employer>();
    
    employers.add("John Smith", "john.smith@example.com", "super123");
}
```

I am just trying to figure out what I am doing wrong or if I have taken the wrong approach.

Comment: Before posting basic "Java 101" questions here, study the [free-of-cost tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) provided by Oracle. Your Question is addressed here:  [*Creating Objects*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html). Also, you could have search for most any Answer to any Question about `ArrayList` and you would see example code to emulate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to explicitly type the class

```
employers.add(new Employer("John Smith", "john.smith@example.com", "super123"));
```

**PS** this will need to be in a code block

Comment: Hi, I have tried to initialize the object separately I believe they're in the same package.

`Employer employer = new Employer("John", "john@example", "super123");
employers.add(employer);`

And 

I have tried to initialize the object in the Employer class too. 
If I am not mistaken wouldn't it already be in code blocks if it is between { } of the class, sorry if that's a dumb question, I'm still very much Java rookie.

Comment: A code block is for example, in a method or Constructor.

Comment: Consider your Employer class, where the fields are defined is not a code block.  The code in the Employer constructor is in a code block.  Usually to start a java class running you need a `main` method.

Answer (score 1):

> private ArrayList < Employer> employers = new ArrayList();
> employers.add("John Smith", "john.smith@example.com", "super123");

Your employers is an `ArrayList` of `Employer` type. So, when you try to add something in the employers list, it will expect something of `Employer` type.
But, in your second line, you are trying to add some string separated by comma. That's why you will not be able to add.
Rather, you have to build your `Employee` object first, then add that like below:

```
Employer employer= new Employer("John Smith", "john.smith@example.com", "super123");
employers.add(employer); //here employer is an object of Employer type
```

Moreover,I see you override the constructor, so define the default constructor too in your `Employer` class:

```
Employer(){};
```

Comment: `Employer(){};` - where in his code is the no-args constructor used?

Comment: It seems that, he is newbie in java. So if in somewhere else he tries to create new object with no arg constructor, it will give error. It is safe side for him.

Answer (score 0):

it seems you missed to create an object of employer before adding it to arrayList.

Answer (score -1):

In here You are using generic. Therefore you can add only Employer object or child class objects of Employer class.

Answer (score -3):

```
  package com.java.avee;

  import java.util.ArrayList;

  public class Employers {

  public static void main(String args[]){
   ArrayList<Employer> employers = new ArrayList<Employer>();
   employers.add(new Employer("John Smith", "john.smith@example.com", 
  "super123"));
 }
}

class Employer {
private String name;
private String email;
private String password;

 Employer(String name, String email, String password){
     this.name = name;
     this.email = email;
     this.password = password;
 }           
}
```

Comment: Please try this you have to create object of type Employer and then add to list

Comment: This will not compile, since statements have to be inside of a code block.

Comment: why it will not compile ?

Comment: Well, since you now edited it, the comment does not apply anymore.